# Discrete Math need some help!

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm taking discrete math course now and need some help on this question. THX!!
T/F or unknown?

1. There is a function that is both $O(n^2)$ and $\Omega(n^3)$.
2. Given two functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, if $g(n) = O(f(n))$ and $f(n) = O(n^2)$, then $g(n) = O(n^5)$.
3. Given two functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, if $g(n) = O(f(n))$ and $f(n) = O(n^2)$, then $g(n) = \Omega(n)$.

I think the first one is false, but not sure about other two. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re right about the first one; I’ll prove it. Then I’ll point you in the right direction for the other two; see if you can finish them on your own, but if you get stuck, feel free to leave a comment.

1. Suppose that $f(n)$ is both $O(n^2)$ and $\Omega(n^3)$. Then there are positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ and an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $|f(n)|\le c_1n^2$ and $|f(n)|\ge c_2n^3$ for all $n\ge m$. But then for all $n\ge m$ we must have $$c_2n^3\le|f(n)|\le c_1n^2$$ and hence $c_2n\le c_1$, which is clearly false when $n>\frac{c_1}{c_2}$. Thus, there is no such $f(n)$: you were correct.
2. The hypotheses imply that there are $c_1,c_2>0$ and $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $|g(n)|\le c_1|f(n)|$ and $|f(n)|\le c_2n^2$ for all $n\ge m$. Can you find an inequality relating $|g(n)|$ to $n^2$? What about to $n^5$?
3. What if $f$ and $g$ are both constant functions?

Comment: I guess they are both F?

Comment: @Mandy: (3) is false, but (2) is true: $|g(n)|\le c_1c_2n^2$, so $g(n)$ is $O(n^2)$ and therefore automatically $O(n^5)$.